# Enabling macros on a new copied workbook using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, security

I have a workbook that has a sub that creates a temporary copy of the workbook which I do some work on.  The problem is when I try to run the macros on the temporary workbook, if the user doesn't have macros always enabled, I get this:
[image]
which causes my sub to not work correctly.

Is there a way to enable the macros for the temporary workbook?  I understand why someone wouldn't always want to always have macros enabled for their Excel, but if they already chose to enable macros for the original workbook, can I use that to carry on to my temporary workbooks?

Comment: Are you opening the new workbook in a different instance of Excel ?  A bit more detail about the exact steps would be useful.

Comment: I'm using (sheet name).Copy.  Not sure if that creates a new instance of Excel or not.  Then I set my workbook variable: set tempWB = activeworkbook.

Comment: Please show your code, otherwise it's difficult to say what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

In short, no.  Macros have to be explicitly enabled on a per workbook basis unless macro security is completely disabled.  Doing anything else would be a massive security hole.  Your "sub that creates a temporary copy of the workbook" is somebody else's "sub that downloads a malicious workbook and executes the code inside it".  You can either run ***all*** of your code from the originating workbook's security context or find some replacement for your workflow that requires a "temporary workbook".

Comment: Can't test right now, but if I use VBA to open a macro-containing workbook I'm pretty sure it doesn't prompt to enable macros for that workbook.  You're already running VBA on the user's system, so at that point all is already lost (from a macro security standpoint)

Comment: If your Excel's Trust Center Settings is already set to "Enable all macros", then the prompt won't show up.  What I've noticed is even with the "Disable all macros with notification" setting, my code will work about half the time without issue.

Also agree with your second point regarding macro security.  That's why I was wondering if the security settings could "carry over".

Comment: @TimWilliams - Interesting.  When I was testing it, I was getting the error every time on my work PC.  Now that I'm testing it again in a VM, it seems to depend on the folder I save the temporary workbook in.